# LTspice can't find definition of model

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, pspice

I am trying to simulate the [TPS54331](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS54331#design-tools-simulation) in LTspice, and I keep getting a "Can't find definition of model MBR340" error message when I run the simulation.

[image]

It looks like the MBR340 is a sub circuit in the TPS54331 model, so I am not really sure what to do here.

[image]

Comment: Put a new diode onto a schematic, right click it. On the popup, click the "type" column to sort by type. Scroll down for 'Schottky' -- they should be in the list together, now. See if you can find an MBR340. If not, you need to add a model. Try IS=1.53831n RS=38.8714m N=647.188m EG=633.686m XTI=0.5 BV=40 IBV=200u CJO=766.349p VJ=0.4 M=428.931m FC=0.5 TT=0 Vpk=40 for the diode model parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe you are a victim of poor SPICE model authoring practice.  The `TPS54331_TRANS` subcircuit utilizes and relies on an external model/library for the MBR340 diode.  The proper practice would be to have all models used within the subcircuit, to actually be included inside the subcircuit definition or library file itself.  Although LTspice can run PSpice models and auto-translate PSpice-specific syntax, it cannot overcome the discrepancy when the library author unintentionally uses a component model outside the subcircuit definition.  This problem doesn't go noticed by Texas Instruments because TI only tests and validates its PSpice models within PSpice, and PSpice always has the external model available since it's built-in to the program.

---

The best way for you to get around this would be to fix the problem yourself.  Fortunately, LTspice's built-in diode component library contains an almost identical diode model so at least you don't have to go hunting for one.  Open a new schematic and put down a diode symbol.  Right-click it and click "Pick New Diode".

[image]

Click on the `Part No.` header to sort by part number and then scroll down to MRBS340 (the "S" means the surface mount version for this diode).  Click on that line so it's highlighted in blue, then press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> which will copy the SPICE `.model` definition to your clipboard.

[image]

Open your TPS54331 `.lib` file in a text editor, either the one built into LTspice or another you prefer.  Scroll down to the line that says `.ENDS TPS54331_TRANS` and add an extra line above it so you can paste in [<kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>] the `.model` definition from your clipboard.  Lastly, remove the `S` from `MBRS340` on that line.  After doing all that, the text in that area of the file should look something like this:

```
+  dff_basic PARAMS:
X_U42_S2    U42_N01674 GND BOOT U42_N01108 POWERSTAGE_U42_S2 
D_U42_D7         PH U42_N00836 MBR340 
X_U42_U5         U42_N14330321 U42_N14330317 INV_DELAY_BASIC PARAMS: DELAY=10N
X_U42_U8         U42_N14330333 U42_N14379753 U42_N14374249 AND2_BASIC
R_U42_R35         U42_N01674 U42_IN1  10k  
R_U42_R34         U42_N14330333 U42_N14330309  135.7  
C_U42_C57         GND U42_N14330333  1n  
C_U42_C58         GND U42_IN1  20p  
X_U42_F2    VIN U42_N00618 VIN U42_N00718 POWERSTAGE_U42_F2 
X_U46         N67911 ECO N68385 N67943 AND3_BASIC
.model MBR340 D(Is=22.6u Rs=.042 N=1.094 Cjo=480p M=.61 Eg=.69 Xti=2 Iave=3 Vpk=40 mfg=OnSemi type=Schottky)
.ENDS TPS54331_TRANS

*$
.subckt SOFT_START_U48_S6 1 2 3 4  
S_U48_S6         3 4 1 2 _U48_S6
RS_U48_S6         1 2 1G
.MODEL         _U48_S6 VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=2e3 Voff=1.0V Von=3.0V
.ends SOFT_START_U48_S6
*$
```

Save the file and then try running your simulation again.